# Wrong php version - laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, xampp

I have a problem with the PHP version after running php --version. It should be the 5.6.40 PHP version, but after running this command into my Laravel (php --version), it shows PHP 8.2.40, but when I try to run phpinfo(), it shows 5.6.40 (this is the version I need, not 8.2.40). What am I going to do?

should be the 5.6.40 PHP version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.